# Link view button with the code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am learning IOS development, and I have a question about the connection with the view (designed on Interface Builder) an my controller, that has the code. How can I connect both and make things like set a properties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways....

The quickest is with Xcode 4+ using Interface Builder and Assistant view.

Open your NIB (xib file) and touched the Assistant view button at the top right of the screen, looks like a tuxedo (outlined in red in screenshot below). This will load the associated interface/header file for this NIB.

Select your button and hold the CTRL key and drag to your header file and point where you want the declaration to be placed as seen below.

[image]

Release the mouse and setup the connection as shown below.

[image]

Once this is completed you will have a method added to your implementation file where you can write your code for what happens when the button is touched.